# i get error in jquery of piczoomer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get Error in this line of pic Zoomer js jquery.picZoomer.js

```
picBDOffset = {x:$picBD.offset().left,y:$picBD.offset().top};
```

Error :

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you show the part of script where you assign value to `$picBD` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
picBDOffset = {x:$picBD.offset()?$picBD.offset().left:0,y:$picBD.offset()?$picBD.offset().top:0};
```

Comment: my problem has been solved thanks for your answer :)